# Understanding fixed width integer types

Tags: c++, fixed-size-types

I understand the idea of fixed width types, but I am little confused by the explanation provided by the reference:

> signed integer type with width of exactly 8, 16, 32 and 64 bits respectively
>   with no padding bits and using 2's complement for negative values
>   **(provided only if the implementation directly supports the type)**

So as far as I understand, if I was able to compile an application, everything should work on platforms which are able to run it. There are my questions:

1. What if some platform does not provide support for those types? Is some kind of alignment used or can the application not at all?
2. If we have a guarantee that `sizeof(char)` is exactly one byte on every platform, regardless of byte size which can be different among platforms, does it mean that `int8_t` and `uint8_t` are guaranteed to be available everywhere?

Answer (score 3):

If the implementation does not provide the type you used, it will not exist and your code will not compile. Manual porting will be needed in this case.

Regarding your second question: while we know that `sizeof(char) == 1`, it is not guaranteed that `char` has exactly eight bits; it can have more than that. If that is the case `int8_t` and friends will not exist.

Note that there are other types that might provide sufficient guarantees for your use case if you don't need to know the exact width, such as `int_least8_t` or `int_fast8_t`. Those leave the implementation some more freedom, making them more portable.

However, if you are targeting a platform on which common integer types do not exist, you should know that in advance anyway; so it is not worth spending too much time working around those most likely irrelevant issues. Those platforms are relatively exotic.

Comment: I just realized how stupid the second question was. *8_t is releated to number of bits. :)

Comment: But how does probable scenario look like? Considering windows, linux, and mac, both x86 and x64, are those types rather supported or not?

Comment: @KasataAta On all "normal" platforms, all of the common types exist. If you have to target more exotic systems like an IBM mainframe (`CHARBIT == 9` iirc) or embedded systems like digital cameras, things might look different. But you'll know when you get there.

Comment: If you're only interested in x86 platforms, you'll be able to use all the types mentioned.  Platforms lacking 8-bit types tend to be DSPs or mainframes (possibly some minis, too), and you should use the more portable types if there's any chance your code might be compiled for those.